# how to use where condition in sql query after data encrypted

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is that possible to use where condition in sql after converting data in to encrypted?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: What kind of encryption are you talking about? Data-at-rest encryption of the database files? That should be transparent to data users.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Encrypted Columns in WHERE Clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3560707/sql-encrypted-columns-in-where-clause)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not if there is any kind of salt (such as an IV) involved in the encryption. In that case, every time you encrypt the same plaintext you will get a different ciphertext, so that you cannot search for it anymore.

[It appears that this is the case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3560707/sql-encrypted-columns-in-where-clause) with SQL Server's EncryptByKey facility.

Comment: Encryption is done in sql itself. i insert the data using following query                                  INSERT INTO dbo.Customer(UserId , FirstName,   LastName, dbpassword)
VALUES
(EncryptByKey(Key_GUID('Key4CellEncryption'),'3'),EncryptByKey(Key_GUID('Key4CellEncryption'),'bala'),EncryptByKey(Key_GUID('Key4CellEncryption'),'malaichamy'),EncryptByKey(Key_GUID('Key4CellEncryption'),'bala'))

Comment: Encryption is done by using following example. http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/granular-or-cell-level-encryption-in-sql-server.html