# How to conditionally check Symmetric Encryption with AES_256 algorithm data with variable data

Tags: sql-server, database, encryption, symmetric-key

I'm using AES_256 algorithm

```
SELECT count(1)
from [dbo].[EmployeeMaster]
where [UserName]=EncryptByKey (Key_GUID('Symmetrickey'),'Username')
```

Here a value with matched case, but result is '0'

with this code i'll get result. but i have huge amount of data for comparing this

```
SELECT count(1)
from [dbo].[EmployeeMaster]
where CONVERT(nvarchar, DecryptByKey([UserName]))='Username'
```

Can anyone suggest me a better way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Encrypted Columns in WHERE Clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3560707/sql-encrypted-columns-in-where-clause)

Comment: The encryption mode is not ECB, therefore tou can't;